# Simplify a formula with 449 terms - Radical circle

Tags: calculus, geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

### Context

The other day I wanted to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4836431/coordinates-of-the-power-center).

> Which is now closed so doesn't accept answers (but this isn't the important part).

Since I didn't know the topic I went to look it up but I saw that there isn't much about it online, so out of curiosity I wanted to see what the formula for [the center and the radical radius was](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_center_(geometry)).

I consider 3 generic circles in the Cartesian plane:
$$c_i: (x-x_i)^2+(y-y_i)^2=r_i^2\qquad\text{for }i=1,2,3$$

By doing a few steps I arrived at these formulas:
$$\mathbf{C}=(x_C,y_C)=\left(\frac{\begin{vmatrix}
y_2y_3+x_1^2-r_1^2&y_1&1\\
y_3y_1+x_2^2-r_2^2&y_2&1\\
y_1y_2+x_3^2-r_3^2&y_3&1
\end{vmatrix}}{2\begin{vmatrix}
x_1&y_1&1\\x_2&y_2&1\\x_3&y_3&1
\end{vmatrix}}, \frac{\begin{vmatrix}
x_1&x_2x_3+y_1^2-r_1^2&1\\
x_2&x_3x_1+y_2^2-r_2^2&1\\
x_3&x_1x_2+y_3^2-r_3^2&1
\end{vmatrix}}{2\begin{vmatrix}
x_1&y_1&1\\x_2&y_2&1\\x_3&y_3&1
\end{vmatrix}}\right)$$
and
$$r=\begin{cases}\sqrt{\left(x_C-x_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(y_C-y_{1}\right)^{2}-r_{1}^{2}}\\
\sqrt{\left(x_C-x_{2}\right)^{2}+\left(y_C-y_{2}\right)^{2}-r_{2}^{2}}\\
\sqrt{\left(x_C-x_{3}\right)^{2}+\left(y_C-y_{3}\right)^{2}-r_{3}^{2}}\end{cases}$$

### Question

The 3 formulas for calculating the radius are all equivalent and correct, but I would like them not to depend so directly on a specific center.

In simple words: I would like a formula that is "regular/symmetrical" like the one for the center and that it does not directly depend on the fact of necessarily having to calculate $x_C$ and $y_C$ first, because I'm pretty sure it can be written as the ratio of two determinants of some matrix (the denominator matrix is ​​that of the determinant of the coordinates of the centers).

Obviously I tried to develop the formulas but the formulas are excessively long (only the term $(x_C-x_1)^2$ alone contains [224 monomials](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=expand%20%28%28f-d%29%28%28b*f%2Bc%5E2-s%5E2%29-%28d*f%2Ba%5E2-r%5E2%29%29-%28d-b%29%28%28b*d%2Be%5E2-t%5E2%29-%28b*f%2Bc%5E2-s%5E2%29%29-2a%28%28f-d%29%28c-a%29-%28d-b%29%28e-c%29%29%29%5E2), so in total there are 449 terms), could anyone help me in some way to obtain the formula efficiently?

Essentially there would be this calculation to do:

$$r=\sqrt{\left(\frac{\begin{vmatrix}
y_2y_3+x_1^2-r_1^2&y_1&1\\
y_3y_1+x_2^2-r_2^2&y_2&1\\
y_1y_2+x_3^2-r_3^2&y_3&1
\end{vmatrix}}{2\begin{vmatrix}
x_1&y_1&1\\x_2&y_2&1\\x_3&y_3&1
\end{vmatrix}}-x_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{\begin{vmatrix}
x_1&x_2x_3+y_1^2-r_1^2&1\\
x_2&x_3x_1+y_2^2-r_2^2&1\\
x_3&x_1x_2+y_3^2-r_3^2&1
\end{vmatrix}}{2\begin{vmatrix}
x_1&y_1&1\\x_2&y_2&1\\x_3&y_3&1
\end{vmatrix}}-y_{1}\right)^{2}-r_{1}^{2}}$$

Answer (score 4):

My approach of solving this would be the following: There must be one number $r$ such that
$$
(x_C-x_1)^2+(y_C-y_1)^2-r_1^2=r^2 \\
(x_C-x_2)^2+(y_C-y_2)^2-r_2^2=r^2 \\
(x_C-x_3)^2+(y_C-y_3)^2-r_3^2=r^2
$$
simultaneously. We can rearrange this and obtain
$$
x_1x_C+y_1y_C+\frac{1}{2}(r^2-x_C^2-y_C^2)=\frac{1}{2}(x_1^2+y_1^2-r_1^2) \\
x_2x_C+y_2y_C+\frac{1}{2}(r^2-x_C^2-y_C^2)=\frac{1}{2}(x_2^2+y_2^2-r_2^2) \\
x_3x_C+y_3y_C+\frac{1}{2}(r^2-x_C^2-y_C^2)=\frac{1}{2}(x_3^2+y_3^2-r_3^2)
$$
With $\lambda = \frac{1}{2}(r^2-x_C^2-y_C^2)$, we get
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\
x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\
x_3 & y_3 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_C \\
y_C \\
\lambda
\end{pmatrix}
=
\frac{1}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1^2+y_1^2-r_1^2 \\
x_2^2+y_2^2-r_2^2 \\
x_3^2+y_3^2-r_3^2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Using [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule), we can see that
$$
(x_C,y_C)=\left(
\frac{
\begin{vmatrix}
x_1^2+y_1^2-r_1^2 & y_1 & 1 \\
x_2^2+y_2^2-r_2^2 & y_2 & 1 \\
x_3^2+y_3^2-r_3^2 & y_3 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
}{
2
\begin{vmatrix}
x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\
x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\
x_3 & y_3 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
}
,\frac{
\begin{vmatrix}
x_1 & x_1^2+y_1^2-r_1^2 & 1 \\
x_2 & x_2^2+y_2^2-r_2^2 & 1 \\
x_3 & x_3^2+y_3^2-r_3^2 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
}{
2
\begin{vmatrix}
x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\
x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\
x_3 & y_3 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
}
\right)
$$
and
$$
\lambda =
\frac{
\begin{vmatrix}
x_1 & y_1 & x_1^2+y_1^2-r_1^2 \\
x_2 & y_2 & x_2^2+y_2^2-r_2^2 \\
x_3 & y_3 & x_3^2+y_3^2-r_3^2
\end{vmatrix}
}{
2
\begin{vmatrix}
x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\
x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\
x_3 & y_3 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
}
$$
from which we get
$$
r^2=2\lambda + x_C^2+y_C^2 = 
\frac{
\begin{vmatrix}
x_1 & y_1 & x_1^2+y_1^2-r_1^2 \\
x_2 & y_2 & x_2^2+y_2^2-r_2^2 \\
x_3 & y_3 & x_3^2+y_3^2-r_3^2
\end{vmatrix}
}{
\begin{vmatrix}
x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\
x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\
x_3 & y_3 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
}
+x_C^2+y_C^2
$$
which is symmetrical with respect to the centers and radii of the circles. I do not know if this can be simplified any further. If you want one fraction of determinants, you can write it as
$$
r^2= 
\frac{
\begin{vmatrix}
x_1 & y_1 & x_1^2+y_1^2-r_1^2+x_C^2+y_C^2 \\
x_2 & y_2 & x_2^2+y_2^2-r_2^2+x_C^2+y_C^2 \\
x_3 & y_3 & x_3^2+y_3^2-r_3^2+x_C^2+y_C^2
\end{vmatrix}
}{
\begin{vmatrix}
x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\
x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\
x_3 & y_3 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
}
$$
Note: In order to see why
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
x_1^2+y_1^2-r_1^2 & y_1 & 1 \\
x_2^2+y_2^2-r_2^2 & y_2 & 1 \\
x_3^2+y_3^2-r_3^2 & y_3 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
x_1^2+y_2y_3-r_1^2 & y_1 & 1 \\
x_2^2+y_3y_1-r_2^2 & y_2 & 1 \\
x_3^2+y_1y_2-r_3^2 & y_3 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
$$
subtract $(y_1+y_2+y_3)$ times the second column from the first column and then add $(y_2y_3+y_3y_1+y_1y_2)$ times the third column to the first column in the left matrix.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple formula for the centre: the $x$-coordinate is
$$\frac{\sum((r_i^2+x_i^2)(-y_{i+1}+y_{i+2})}
{2\sum (x_i y_{i+1}-x_{i+1}y_i)}.
$$
The sums are from $1$ to $3$.
We are using the usual ploy of extending the labels cyclically, i.e. $x_4=x_1$, etc.
The $y$ coordinate is obtained from the same formula after exchanging $x$ and $y$.

It is then a simple task to obtain the formula for the radius

I posted a brief description of how this formula can be derived but it has been deleted.